# where to download for apple's open source core foundation?

Tags: c++, core-foundation

where should I download the core foundation library?  I have a program that includes CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h ...  It is an iPhone app, but I'm thinking the core foundation code will run on linux.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All Apple's open source code can be found in http://opensource.apple.com/. The source code of Core Foundation (actually, "CFLite") can be found in http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635.19/, and can be downloaded from http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/CF/CF-635.19.tar.gz.

The [README](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635.19/README_CFLITE) file describes how to build the library on Linux. Note that not the full Core Foundation is available.

> The Mac OS X version of CFLite supports most of the functionality of the full CoreFoundation. The Linux version of CFLite focuses on strings, dates, collections, and other property-list related items.

Comment: It's worth noting it hasn't been updated since OS X 10.10, which was a while ago. You can find a more updated version in the swift-corelibs-foundation repository. https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/tree/main/CoreFoundation