# build project visual c++ failing - missing files

Tags: c++, dll, build

I'm trying to build the itunnel_mux project here:

https://code.google.com/p/iphonetunnel-usbmuxconnectbyport/ The source for the project build is here - http://iphonetunnel-usbmuxconnectbyport.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/itnl/win32_project/

However, for some reason there are missing files that it's looking for. CoreFoundation.lib, iTunesMobileDevice and libMobiledevice.lib.

I'm wondering how I can obtain these? According to their help section someone was able to build the lib files from dll's https://code.google.com/p/iphonetunnel-usbmuxconnectbyport/issues/detail?id=5

However, none of these dll's are included within the src and it's unclear where these dlls are supposed to come from. Do I have to build the dlls from source and then build the lib files from them?

A bit confused generally about this build and would be grateful if anyone knows the right direction.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either have to generate those .libs from source or find them online somewhere.
If you want to build them yourself (which I recommend) take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959358/where-to-download-for-apples-open-source-core-foundation).