# Transfer files from iOS device to Windows PC via USB

Tags: c++, ios, windows

In my C++ Windows application, my users can plug in their mobile device via USB and my application can transfer specific files to/from the device. For Android devices, I was able to use MTP. But iOS devices have me tripped up (I'm not an iOS user).

Immediately, I saw that MTP wasn't an option as I couldn't view the device's filesystem via Windows Explorer (wasn't expecting that). So now I'm stuck, and confused. Googled like crazy and all I discovered was that other 3rd party programs can do it, but I can't find any documentation or resources as to HOW.

Can someone point me in the right direction? What would I need to do in order to view the filesystem on a connected iOS device? Are there any libraries I may be unaware of that I can't find? I can see that iTunes has the functionality I'm looking for.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Unfortunately what you ask for is not supported because Apple thinks their users don't need it :). And Apple seems to make it only harder over the years. So I strongly doubt other 3rd party programs can do it unless device is rooted. Could your provide a link to such an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like my comment was wrong. There is at least libimobiledevice http://www.libimobiledevice.org/ and https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse that claims to still support access to the iOS device file system and even claims to be cross-platform. I haven't tried it though to verify if those claims are true.

See also https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/MobileDevice_Library for some possible alternatives

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. I'll look into it and accept this answer when I'm done :) :)

Comment: This turns out to be much more confusing than I had originally thought. I'll accept this answer because it seems correct, but I believe this requires Linux and much more knowledge than I have now. I'll have to devote a lot of time to implement this properly. Thanks though!

Comment: @mc360pro, that's bad news. Have you tried only "libimobiledevice" or did you also explored the avenue that uses the dll from iTunes refrenced in the wiki I mentioned (such as ones that the guy at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885368/build-project-visual-c-failing-missing-files tried)?

Comment: Well I realized libimobiledevice is not as simple as adding a library and boom I have file access. At least that was my takeaway after browsing trying to find any guide or documentation. I've never been well versed when it comes to libraries or compiling other people's code AT ALL. They confuse the heck out of me. Let alone reverse engineering the dll to make my own library I can rely on.